# I'm having some trouble in the below propositional logic question.

Tags: propositional-calculus

How to write the statement for the following?

> If it does not rain, then if we go swimming then we have to take the bus.

I have been confused with the above "then" repetition...

Comment: Two nested "if..., then...". The inner one is "if we go swimming then we have to take the bus", i.e. $(\text {we go Swimming } \to \text {we have to take the Bus})$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA does not rain=> R, go swiming => S, take bus=> B
Then how the final result would be is it like R → ( S → B) is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p =$ “It is raining.”, $q =$ “We will swim.” and $r =$ “We are taking the bus.”. The proposition that we have is

> If it does not rain, then if we go swimming then we have to take the bus.

As pointed at the answer given by Jotabeta, we have that this proposition has the form

\begin{align*}
\neg p \implies (q \implies r)
\end{align*}

You have an hypothesis that is $p$ (If it does not rain), but then at the conclusion you other implication, i.e., the conclusion itself is another implication, namely $q \implies r$. Then, you just put all together.

Also, you can check by yourself, it would be the same if we have written $(\neg p \wedge q) \implies r$. You can use a truth table to immediately conclude that

\begin{align*}
(\neg p \Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow r)) \iff ((\neg p \wedge q) \Rightarrow r)
\end{align*}

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you so much for the observation. It was my mistake. I already edited. Further observations are welcomed.

Comment: @AirMike thanks it helped a lot

Comment: @NiroshanRatnayake you’re welcomed. Any further doubt, just ask. Good work.

Answer (score 1):

Let

Does not rain $\equiv A$

Go swimming $\equiv B$

Take the bus $\equiv C$

the n your statement becomes $A → [B →  C]$. For better understanding, you can say: Assume that it doesn't rain, then if we go swimming then we take the bus.

Comment: In propositional logic, "not" is a connective.

Comment: A → ( B → C) this is it right @Jotabeta?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake, you are right, i corrected it.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA  So this is the answer, right? A → ( B → C)

Comment: Yes, it is the answer.